# Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 554

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendmail

Im using email in my website, when i try to send email it show an error

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 554 Sending address not accepted due to spam filter

can anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: `Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 554 Sending address not accepted due to spam filter`: An error couldn't have been more specific than that

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because your IP address have been **blacklisted** as spammer & is currently blocked by the mail server. In order to resolve this, try contacting your server host and ask them to remove your IP from blacklist or if you are using a dynamic IP, try restarting your modem to get a new IP